# Should I use ISPConfig distro on my VPS?

Tags: vps

I recently get a VPS to put a CMS on it. The use of this VPS will be pretty basic : LAMP, mail, and SSL...

I'm used to admin all my servers with command line directly throw SSH. But this server will be administrate with a friend who don't really got skills on sysadmin.
I ask me about Debian with an ISPconfig install.

To be honnest i never heard about it before this. I check the docs, some blogs around but i can't get the big picture.

Is ISPConfig really worth it? What is, in your opinion, the pro and the cons to it ?

I mean do you guys got some feedback about use and security issue with it ? Do you think it will be really easier for my friend ?

Thx !

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is ISPConfig really worth it?

No.

> I mean do you guys got some feedback about use and security issue with
>   it ?

ISPConfig will most definitely provide an additional attack surface. But beyond that, by relying on the GUI, you're not learning the skills needed to troubleshoot issues or those necessary to even detect if something is awry on the server or if you've been compromised. Believe me, if your server gets compromised, ISPConfig is **not** going to help you figure out what's going on. You're going to need to get down and dirty with your ssh client and muck about on the command line.

> Do you think it will be really easier for my friend ?

Initially yes, in the long term, no.

You're in the business of linux administration. You (and your friend) really ought to learn the proper way to administrate linux servers, which is on the command line. Delaying that learning process by installing a web GUI is only hampering your admin abilities and your understanding of what's really going on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's exactly what i tought when i see it. I really don't like GUI for servers...